# Hiding status bar in android when activity starts

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hello I m writing android application I m using BottomSheet in an activity and when the activity starts I m loading that activity from bottom by overriding the animation but problem is when activity loads from bottom up the status bar also peeks up. I don't not need the status bar peeking how to hide it ?

and I set the status bar color to transparent and even I tried with full screen also but it doesn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `oncreate` write

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)

Answer (score 0):

**In your activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```